# How do I decrypt a openpgp email?

Tags: 11.10, openpgp

I recently installed quickly to develop an ubuntu application (my first). I looked at the tutorial videos at *developer.ubuntu.com*. I followed all the steps and then ran **quickly release** at which point it asked me to create a OpenPGP key. So I created one and it took some time to get it uploaded to the Ubuntu keyserver. Now, I imported the key to launchpad. I got an email to my hotmail account which I need to decrypt. I have no idea how to do it.

In the email, it provided a link showing the instructions but they were specific to an email client like thunderbird, evolution etc. So I forwarded the email to my gmail account which I have configured in thunderbird. I installed the enigmail plugin. But I still do not know how to decrypt the message.

Why can't this be a bit more simpler. I mean all the instructions up until this were clear and easy to follow but this one step is really annoying. Please help.

Edit: I have Thunderbird 7 and Enigmail 1.3.2 installed. I do not see the option to automatically decrypt the email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default enigmail will decrypt - see http://www.rainydayz.org/node/108 for guidance. If it doesn't, check the OpenPGP → Automatically Decrypt/Verify Messages option is checked.

Comment: I have solved the problem as it automatically decrypted it. However, I do not see the option OpenPGP → Automatically Decrypt/Verify Messages.

Comment: Do you have the OpenPGP menubar item? It should be under there - see the screenshots on the wikipedia page.

Comment: I have OpenPGP menubar item.  I checked them but couldn't find it. But I see the lock icon to show that the message was decrypted. All that works.